# Vagrant Config Error - "A box must be specified."

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

The boxes were working fine. Then I halted one (the only one running at the time) and now I can't get either of them back up.

---

Running `vagrant up [name]` gives me the following error, regardless of which I pick or whether I leave it at `vagrant up` for them both to come up:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

Running latest version of Vagrant (1.7.4).

Here is my Vagrantfile in its entirety, comments included (just in case):

```
# Search for boxes here: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search
# Refer to commands_vagrant.txt for command reference

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # Globally defined variables
    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/public"

    # CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.5.36 (-u root), PHP 5.3.28
    # Note: If PHP session keys don't work, set permissions to 777 (or other more restrictive, but this is guaranteed to work) on /var/lib/php/session
    config.vm.define "php5dot3", primary: true do |php5dot3|
        config.vm.box = "smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp"
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
    end

    # Ubuntu 14.04 (SSH pw: vagrant), Apache 2.4.12, MySQL 5.5.43 (-u root -p root), PHP 5.6.10
    config.vm.define "php5dot6" do |php5dot6|
        config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4568
    end

end
```

---

Result of running `vagrant status`:

```
Current machine states:

php5dot3                  poweroff (virtualbox)
php5dot6                  poweroff (virtualbox)
```

---

Result of running `vagrant global-status`:

```
id       name     provider   state    directory                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
e1f3c85  default  virtualbox poweroff /home/sam/Web                       
c588d51  php5dot6 virtualbox poweroff /home/sam/Web                       
4e71c50  php5dot3 virtualbox poweroff /home/sam/Web
```

'default' was the singular box I had in my Vagrantfile before I got multi-machines working last week. (Relevant?)

---

Result of running `vagrant box list`:

```
scotch/box                          (virtualbox, 2.0)
smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
```

---

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I created a similar issue here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6245

Comment: did you run `bash init.sh`before ?

Comment: Nope, never run any bash scripts in relation to Vagrant.

Comment: i had the same problem, got it solved by running that line. the paths on your `homestead.yaml` that points to the ssh files should also be correct.

Comment: Not using Homestead here, just Vagrant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside of your machine definitions, you need to use the variable name of that machine, instead of `config`. Try this out:

In the file below, I've changed `config.vm` to either `php5dot3.vm` or `php5dot6.vm`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # Globally defined variables
    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/public"

    # CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.5.36 (-u root), PHP 5.3.28
    # Note: If PHP session keys don't work, set permissions to 777 (or other more restrictive, but this is guaranteed to work) on /var/lib/php/session
    config.vm.define "php5dot3", primary: true do |php5dot3|
        php5dot3.vm.box = "smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp"
        php5dot3.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
    end

    # Ubuntu 14.04 (SSH pw: vagrant), Apache 2.4.12, MySQL 5.5.43 (-u root -p root), PHP 5.6.10
    config.vm.define "php5dot6", autostart:false do |php5dot6|
        php5dot6.vm.box = "scotch/box"
        php5dot6.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4568
    end

end
```

I also added `autostart:false` to the definition of your `php5dot6` box, which you can remove if you wish. (It just means that running `vagrant up` will only start the primary by default.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my long-standing issue with Vagrant. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wish you hadn't had to wait 4 months for the issue to be resolved!

Comment: Bright side? Problem solved! Flip side? ...How did I not figure this out... :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error with DigitalOcean, you may need their plugin:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-digitalocean
Installing the 'vagrant-digitalocean' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: faraday-0.15.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: vagrant-digitalocean-0.9.3.gem (100%)
```

Comment: This solved my problem for DigitalOcean on Vagrant 2.2.5. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome my friend. I am glad I could save someone some time. If this was helpful please upvote so others can find it as well.

Answer (score 1):

For someone that is having this issue now:

I had deleted my Vagrantfile before trying to destroy it. You need to run the `vagrant destroy` command from the right directory where the Vagrantfile for that process is.

Run `vagrant ssh-config` and look at the directory column.

If you, like me, deleted the file, do:

```
vagrant init
```

Then

```
vagrant destroy $id
```

P.S.: Use `sudo` if you have permission issues running those commands.